# App not finding chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

All of a sudden half of my devices have stopped finding my Chromecasts I'm testing on. I thought it was some code I changed so I decided to make a bare bones implementation that finds the media routes. This implementation only works on my 4.0.4 Toshiba Thrive but not on any other devices. I thought it was my network so I reset the router, when that didn't work I bought a new router but that has also failed. My colleagues have tested the apk and it works on their devices on a different network with different chromecasts. I have factory reset both my chromecasts and verified that all my devices are on the latest version of Google Play Services.

```
public class CastTestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cast_test);

    MediaRouter mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
    MediaRouteSelector mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("XXXXXXXX")).build();

    mediaRouter.addCallback(mediaRouteSelector, new MediaRouter.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteAdded(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_ADDED", String.valueOf(route));
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteRemoved(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_REMOVED", String.valueOf(route));
        }
        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteSelected(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_SELECTED", String.valueOf(route));

        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteUnselected(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_UNSELECTED", String.valueOf(route));
        }


        @Override
        public void onRouteChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteChanged(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_CHANGED", String.valueOf(route));
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteVolumeChanged(router, route);
            Log.d("ROUTE_VOLUME", String.valueOf(route));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.ProviderInfo provider) {
            super.onProviderAdded(router, provider);
            Log.d("ROUTE_PROVIDER_ADDED", String.valueOf(provider));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.ProviderInfo provider) {
            super.onProviderRemoved(router, provider);
            Log.d("ROUTE_PROVIDER_REMOVED", String.valueOf(provider));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.ProviderInfo provider) {
            super.onProviderChanged(router, provider);
            Log.d("ROUTE_PROVIDER_CHANGED", String.valueOf(provider));
        }
    }, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);

    MediaRouteButton button = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    button.setRouteSelector(mediaRouteSelector);

}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
...
```

}

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.+"
```

}

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Logs from 4.3 Nexus 7 that find no routes
https://gist.github.com/darussian/9957516

Logs from 4.0.4 Toshiba Thrive that finds routes
https://gist.github.com/darussian/9957547

Those two logs are the same apk. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was Factory resetting all of my devices that were not finding the chromecasts. I'm assuming that something got cached in Google Play Services that clearing the cache could not resolve. Since re installing GMS is not an option reformatting was the only option.